# Can you specify a CouchDB replication filter on the receiving database?

Tags: couchdb

There is an excellent article here (https://momentum.spindance.com/2016/02/couchdb-replications/) with useful information on CouchDB replication. And looking at the documentation it is easy to find reference to replication filters (e.g. http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html).

However they all seem to involve filtering what the changes feed will emit. I would like a master CouchDB to emit all the docs, and then several slaves to only store the docs that fit within their ID range.

Is it possible to do this with a filter in a design document?

Otherwise could this be done with a validate document update function on the slaves and a push replication on the master?

Slaves and master is actually misleading, as info will be inserted into the 'slaves' each of which needs to have a subset of info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for this](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Named_Document_Replication) doesn't seem to have made it across to the new wiki, but yes, you can do Named Document Replication by providing a `doc_ids` attribute in your replication document.

#### Update following OP comment

Sorry, I realized I didn't answer your core question. No, you can't have the filter on the receiver. Filtering is done on the whole doc, so even if you could Couch would require all the full docs on the receiver before it could filter them anyway, so you'd be transferring all the documents even if you were able to do this.

You can, btw, just have a second DB on the receiver that replicates all the docs from the master, and then have **it** define the filter for your filtered replication to your other DB on the receiver.

...and yes, for Named Document Replication you have to provide all IDs, and no, there's no limit to the size of that data.

One other thing that you might not have thought of, the filter function is just part of a design doc, and all docs (including design docs) can be replicated. So you can actually create the filter on the receivers if you wish, and then replicate them up to the master, and then use them from the receiver in filtered replication.

Comment: Thank you, that is straightforward. If I have, for example, 50k documents: 10k go to DB1, 10k go to DB2, 10K go to DB3, etc. They will have sequential IDs. It looks like I have to specify every ID for every database? Or can I do ranges. For this reason a filter function seems better. If I define the filter function on the receiving database, can you do that on the replication document? Alternatively can you specify 10 000 fields in the way the documentation suggests?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I realized I didn't actually answer your question. I've updated my answer now.

Comment: The last paragraph was particularly helpful. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, just dawned on me as I was writing the rest, good luck.

Comment: Hi one more question. If I were to use a named replication, that replication would need to be updated on a monthly basis. i.e. every month the existing replication would be removed and replaced by a new one with different ids, most of which overlapped. What would happen in this case? Ideally the replication would stop, then the new replication added, then replication would just carry on with only the IDs of the new replications being replicated. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen.